# Google Public DNS is returning a SERVFAIL for my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, google, nslookup, dig

Hope some one will help me in resolving the issue. My Domain name is "prohosterz.com"

Google Public DNS is returning a SERVFAIL for my domain:

```
$ dig prohosterz.com @8.8.8.8

; > DiG 9.9.2 > prohosterz.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER
```

```
$ nslookup -debug prohosterz.com 8.8.8.8
Server:        8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    prohosterz.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find prohosterz.com: SERVFAIL
Server:        8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

------------
    QUESTIONS:
    prohosterz.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
------------
** server can't find prohosterz.com: SERVFAIL
```

I don't have any issues resolving my domain against OpenDNS:

```
$ dig prohosterz.com @resolver1.opendns.com

; > DiG 9.9.2-P1 > prohosterz.com @resolver1.opendns.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER
```

I don't know why google servers do not resolve my name, if anyone have any explanation please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your DNSSEC configuration is broken.

The delegating nameservers (for `com.`) are serving a `DS` record for your domain, but your own nameservers do not supply `DNSKEY` nor `RRSIG` records.

Did you forget to sign the zone?

The reason it works with some recursors is that those recursors are not DNSSEC-enabled and thus don't catch the problem.